# Solve $y'=3\mid y \mid ^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'am trying to find all solutions and the set of points where the initial value problem is not locally unique for the following ODE: \begin{align*}
y'=3\mid y \mid  ^{\frac{2}{3}}=f(t,y) , y\in \mathbb{R} \end{align*}

The first solution is $y\equiv 0$.Now if $y \neq 0$ then we can say:
 $(-y)^{\frac{2}{3}} = y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so I don't have to consider the cases.

Then we have \begin{align*}& \frac{dy}{y^{\frac{2}{3}}} = 3 dt \\ &\Rightarrow  \int y^{\frac{-2}{3}}dy = \int 3 dt \\ &\Rightarrow 3y^{\frac{1}{3}} = 3t+c_{1} \\ &\Rightarrow y = (t+c)^{3} \end{align*}
Is that correct?
How can I find the set of points where the initial value problem is not locally unique?

Comment: The right hand side is smooth for $y \neq 0$, so for such initial conditions you have local uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of $$y=(t+c)^3$$ is correct.

Note that we also have $$y=0$$ as a solution therfore we loose uniqueness for initial points on the $t$ axis.

For example for $y(1)=0$  you have two solutions $$y=(t-1)^3$$ and $$y=0$$ both satisfying the initial condition of $$y(1)=0$$